# Modulus operation finding value sattisfying given condition

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the minimum value of $p$ such that

$5^p \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

What is the approach to solve such questions?

Comment: In this case it is rather simple. Are you familiar with Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @Mark,no i will check it out

Answer (score 2):

*Little Fermat* asserts that if $p $ is prime number, for any number $a$ not divisible by $p$, we have $\;a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$.

The set of congruence classes of integers not divisible by $p$ form a multiplicative group, which has order $p-1$. By *Lagrange's theorem*, the order of an element $a$ of this group (i.e. the smallest $r$ such that $a^k\equiv 1\mod p$) is a divisor of $p-1$. Hence to find the order of an element you have to test a finite number of values.

In the present case the order of $5$ is a divisor of $18$, i.e. it can be $1$ (irrelevant for trivial reasons), $3,6,9$ or $18$.

We can calculate the powers of $5$ by the *fast exponentiation algorithm* (‘square and multiply’, which yields the following values:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
5^2&\equiv 6,\\
&&&5^3\equiv6\cdot5=30\equiv -8&&\mod19,\\
5^4&\equiv6^2\equiv -2,&\qquad&\\
&& &5^6\equiv -2\cdot6\equiv 7&&\mod 19,\\
5^8&\equiv4,\\
&&&5^{\color{red}9}\equiv4\cdot 5\equiv \color{red}1&&\mod 19.
\end{alignat*}
Thus $5$ has order 9 mod. 19.

Comment: why can't "p=2" be a solution

Comment: @Zack Ni: As it is formulated, you're right, and my answer has little to see with the problem. I can't remember why  why I answered it, as it was posted quite some time ago, but maybe the initial formulation was ambiguous. As it is now, for any odd prime $p$, this congruence is false.

Comment: Yup, your answer seems to prove $5^p \equiv 5 \mod p$.  Im not pretty sure whether the p = 19 is the least number for this condition. You can see my answer beneath and I guess a better way you will find to answer this question compared to mine.

Comment: $5^p=5$ is true for *all* primes: that is what Little Fermat says (for any integer $a$).

Answer (score 1):

The minimal $p$ should be $2$, because $5^2\equiv 25\equiv 1\pmod 2 $.

The first condition for the question that should be satisfied is $p>0$ and $p$ must be an integer, otherwise there is no sense talking about the modular equation.

Since it has shown that $2$ is one possible solution, the proposition that

$p = 2$ is the minimal value satisfying the above equation must be proven.

Now that $p > 0$ and $p$ must be a integer, the number less than $2$ is $1$, the statement that $1$ isn't the minimal value must be proven.

Here is the prove:

If $p = 1$, $5^p \equiv 5 \equiv 0  \pmod 1$, so one can't be a solution.

Therefore, $2$ is the minimal value for $ p$ to satisfy.

EDIT: By Bernard, it should be p equals to 1 rather than 2. Because when $p = 1$, $1 \equiv 0 \pmod 1$

Comment: (+1) I would have only one restriction on the case $p=1$: $5\equiv 0$, that is true, but also $0\equiv 1$, so we have $5^1\equiv 1\mod1$. It's uninteresting, and gives one more reason to say the question is not well formulated.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on an Excel spreadsheet shows that p=9 is the answer.  Just write a little program in any language you have on hand.